# Help identifying a mushroom found in Raymond, WA, USA

Tags: species-identification, mycology

Hello dear mycology wizards!

Could you help me figure out what's the name of this species.
I found the mushrooms in a **[forest near to Raymond, WA](https://www.google.com/maps/@46.6986254,-123.713837,1308m/data=!3m1!1e3)**. The area was quite wet and mossy, but not a swamp. There was a creek ~50-75 feet away. The forest is mostly coniferous trees with a few birches.

[image]

Here are the photos of the mushroom of interest:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: just as a preface to any responses you get: I have not known this community to be especially knowledgeable about mushrooms (i.e., I don't know of any mycology wizards here), so I would suggest you research further any answer you receive and/or seek additional insight from a known mycologist. (Not that an answer you get isn't correct, but I think fungi are notoriously tricky to ID and easily misidentified by even trained mycologists -- so do more of your own sleuthing with whatever info you glean from this community). Good luck :).

Comment: [Candy cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candy_cap) is another possibility, which should have brittle stipes, a sweet odor, and a milky latex. However, it can be easily confused with the [deadly galerina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galerina_marginata), so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

To me that looks like [*Chrysomphalina chrysophylla*](https://www.mykoweb.com/CAF/species/Chrysomphalina_chrysophylla.html), which is one of several fungi superficially similar to the [chanterelles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantharellus).

(The chanterelle in contrast has gradual increase in the diameter of the stalk rather than a sharp demarkation between the stalk and cap.)

*Chrysomphalina chrysophylla* is a species that has been reported in Washington:
[image: Chrysomphalina chrysophylla ©Kit Scates Barnhart] Source: [Burke Herbarium Image Collection (for Washington state)](http://biology.burke.washington.edu/herbarium/imagecollection/taxon.php?Taxon=Chrysomphalina%20chrysophylla)

Comment: All the mushrooms I saw on the site had straight, not curved stocks. None of them grew on the dead wood/logs. I suspect it's a different fungi, but I really appreciate your attempt to identify it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure those are false chanterelles. True chanterelles, like Igor said, have a stalk that gradually widens from the base to where the mushroom cap starts, giving then kind of a fat look, if that makes sense. Chanterelles also aren't so garishly orange, they're more of a creamy orange-yellow, and they have more of a ruffled edge on the cap. [image][image]

Be really careful because false chanterelles can make you quite sick. Hope you didn't eat any of those before finding out for sure! Good luck in your hunting

Comment: No, I did not eat any (in fact I didn't even collect them). I found them a year ago when I was shopping for land in that area... Thank you!

Comment: The specimens in OP's photographs don't look like false chanterelles (*Hygrophoropsis aurantiaca*) at all.